# How to use all the fuel in a bottle with a MSR Whisperlite Internationale?

Tags: gear-care, stoves, liquid-fuel-stoves, fuel

I make heavy use of my [MSR Whisperlite Internationale](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Msr-11780-MSR-WhisperLite-Internationale/dp/B000BBS49C), the version from 2010 or so.

[image]

Virtually always I use unleaded gasoline in the small 11 fl oz (325 mL) bottle. I carry a larger bottle for carrying more fuel, but I find using the small bottle in camp is easiest.

The problem is once the level of the fuel in the bottle below 1/4, I can't get the stove to stay lit, regardless of how many times I pump it.

I've noticed that at this low level, if the bottle was sitting upright, the fuel tube and filter are sitting above level of the fuel. Of course I use my fuel bottle lying on its side.

Its quite annoying because there's always a decent portion of fuel I can't burn in the bottle.

I do perform regular maintenance on my stove, though I haven't had to replace any components in a year or so.

Does anyone have any tricks for using the remaining fuel in the bottle? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Most things I can think of would stop it working even when full.

My one suggestion is, is the pump below the fuel line when on its side?

The fuel line is the white tube in the picture. If it is in the middle of the bottle and the fuel is low it might not be submerged when the bottle is horizontal. Have you tried putting the bottle vertically or rotating it?

[image]

Comment: This would be my guess as well. Sometimes the white fuel line curls upwards when the stove is stuffed in your pack. Just bend it back so it looks like in the picture nivag posted.